# What are the differences between two generations of  Tokina AT-X 124 AF PRO DX AF 12-24mm f/4?

Tags: lens, tokina

I have been looking for a wide angle lens for a long time and have finally decided on the Tokina 12-24mm. When I went looking on eBay, I found there are two different types:

- The [Tokina AT-X 124 AF PRO DX AF 12-24mm f/4](http://www.tokinalens.com/products/tokina/afl-00.html)
- The [Tokina AT-X 124 AF PRO DX AF 12-24mm f/4 II](http://www.tokinalens.com/products/tokina/atx124prodx2-a.html)

The only difference I can find is they've put some different coating on the glass – but there has to be more differences than that, right?

Also, does anyone have this lens? If so, what do you think of it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking on DXOMark it appears the new one has its own focussing motor and it's a bit lighter as well as it has a new coating.

Answer (score 1):

Tokina AT-X 124 AF PRO DX AF 12-24mm f/4 II has no screwdriver connection, has fast traditional motor and impossible to autofocus in LV mode in my Nikon D5100. Picture is scharp and attractive.